# How to perform looping in R and export data

Tags: r, loops, recursion, apply, export-to-csv

I have a question, we have generated pilot gene expression data with one sample per condition, this is just a test run. I have a control (baseline) sample followed by 5 different samples and performed analysis using `edgeR` package in R, I want to indicate my **control** sample (as baseline) and calculate **logFC**, **logCPM**, and **PValue** for all samples and export the csv file from the object `et$table`. For instance, Control vs Sample_1, Control vs Sample_2 till Control vs Sample_5 > export csv file. How do I perform looping to export data for all conparisons? We are looking to analyse hundred's of sample and multi-conditions, it will be easier to perform this later on the large datasets.

Thank you,

Toufiq

**Input data**

```
dput(Counts_Test)
structure(list(Control = c(0L, 184L, 60L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 87L, 0L, 
0L, 21L, 193L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 50L, 0L, 325L, 442L), Sample_1 = c(0, 
140.5, 64, 0, 4, 0, 83, 0, 1, 51.5, 199, 25, 0, 0, 5, 62, 0, 
525, 407), Sample_2 = c(0, 169, 45, 1, 3, 0, 122, 0, 0, 36.5, 
179, 20, 0, 0, 1, 58, 0, 494, 570), Sample_3 = c(0L, 107L, 67L, 
0L, 5L, 0L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 63L, 178L, 34L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 60L, 0L, 
467L, 283L), Sample_4 = c(0L, 221L, 44L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 139L, 0L, 
0L, 48L, 222L, 24L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 67L, 0L, 612L, 451L), Sample_5 = c(0, 
120.5, 45, 1, 1, 0, 100, 0, 0, 44.5, 202, 39, 1, 0, 3, 76, 0, 
719, 681)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", 
"Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Gene16", 
"Gene17", "Gene18", "Gene19"))


dput(Sample_Grouping)
structure(list(SampleID = c("xx-xx-1551", "xx-xx-1548", "xx-xx-1549", 
"xx-xx-1550", "xx-xx-1552", "xx-xx-0093"), ID = c("Control", 
"Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Control", 
"Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5"))
```

**Example of the R code and input and expected data given below:**

```
library(edgeR)
bcv <- 0.4
y <- DGEList(counts=Counts_Test, group=Sample_Grouping$ID)
et <- exactTest(y, dispersion=bcv^2)
View(et$table)
write.csv(et$table, file="./table_Control_vs_Sample_1", sep = ",")
```

**Export csv file for et$table on comparison between Control vs Sample_1**

```
dput(et$table)
structure(list(logFC = c(2.56274120305193e-15, -0.550254150196693, 
-0.0683012466357368, 2.56274120305193e-15, -0.946184736817423, 
2.56274120305193e-15, -0.229115434595494, 2.56274120305193e-15, 
3.1003487058189, 1.12824320628868, -0.117305916091926, -0.373934941685134, 
2.56274120305193e-15, 2.56274120305193e-15, 0.557345502442179, 
0.148458971210359, 2.56274120305193e-15, 0.530168392608693, -0.280483136036388
), logCPM = c(10.2398977391586, 16.5699363191385, 15.0947320625249, 
10.459922538352, 11.7193421876963, 10.2398977391586, 15.9893772819593, 
10.2398977391586, 10.3561232675437, 14.7852593647762, 16.8836544336529, 
14.184917355539, 10.4590444918373, 10.2398977391586, 11.6104987130447, 
15.2490804549745, 10.2398977391586, 18.2653428429955, 18.1145148472016
), PValue = c(1, 0.523490569569589, 0.978749897705603, 1, 0.6666864407408, 
1, 0.797857807297049, 1, 1, 0.227758918677035, 0.896097547311082, 
0.732358557879292, 1, 1, 0.788137722865551, 0.88329454414985, 
1, 0.532994222767919, 0.743046444999486)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", 
"Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", 
"Gene16", "Gene17", "Gene18", "Gene19"))
```

**Expected output**

Likewise, it would be great to export csv file for et$table on comparison between Control vs Sample_1, Control vs Sample_2, Control vs Sample_3, Control vs Sample_4, Control vs Sample_5 and add suffix of the sample names to the output csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like what you want?

```
sample_names <- c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5")
for(cur_name in sample_names){
  ...
  write.csv(et$table, file=paste0("./table_Control_vs_",cur_name))
}
```

The `...` indicates the lines where you run edgeR for each comparison.

For each iteration, you can use the `pair` argument in the `exactTest` function to specify the comparison. So, your full code may look like this:

```
sample_names <- c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5")
library(edgeR)
bcv <- 0.4
y <- DGEList(counts=Counts_Test, group=Sample_Grouping$ID)
for(cur_name in sample_names){
  et <- exactTest(y, pair=c("Control", cur_name), dispersion=bcv^2)
  write.csv(et$table, file=paste0("./table_Control_vs_",cur_name))
}
```

Note that the first element in the `pair` argument is taken as the baseline for the comparison by `exactTest`.

You may reply if this does not solve your problem, or select the answer if it does.

A further addition responding to your question below, you can enforce gene order this way:

```
sample_names <- c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5")
library(edgeR)
bcv <- 0.4
y <- DGEList(counts=Counts_Test, group=Sample_Grouping$ID)
for(cur_name in sample_names){
  et <- exactTest(y, pair=c("Control", cur_name), dispersion=bcv^2)
  if(cur_name=="Sample_1"){
    # In the first iteration, capture the order
    geneOrder <- row.names(et$table)
  }else{
    # In the subsequent iterations, enforce the order
    et$table <- et$table[geneOrder,]
  }
  # Now, you can write
  write.csv(et$table, file=paste0("./table_Control_vs_",cur_name))
}
# The if/else statement will ensure the order is the same for all
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, this is resolved. I hope the order of the `rownames (genes)` in all exported files will remain the same. One question, does this have any impact on the order of the rownames (genes)? Incase, If I want to export all the data in one csv file only, then how does the `write.csv` function works?

Comment: To ensure the same gene order, you can easily enforce it across each iteration.  I have edited my original answer to include this part.  Please see above.